# ActiveMQ linux service not accepting --extdir in Application parameters

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm tweaking the wrapper.conf in ActiveMQ so that the service will add an extdir of our camel jars.
In the windows wrapper I was able to change the Application parameters so that it added the extdir to the startup

```
# Application parameters.  Add parameters as needed starting from 1
wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.apache.activemq.console.Main
wrapper.app.parameter.2=--extdir "..\..\lib\companyname"
wrapper.app.parameter.3=start
```

This successfully loads the lib folder at startup on windows machines.

However when I change the linux wrapper.conf to match this it fails and the log shows:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/11/12 06:51:05 | INFO: Unrecognized option: --extdir "..\..\lib\companyname"
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/11/12 06:51:05 | Usage: Main [--extdir <dir>] [task] [task-options] [task data]
```

These tweaks are planned to be chefinised so having the service working is a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by a difference in how the windows and linux JVM handle parameters.

Looking into the service wrapper helped me to figure this out. 
http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-app-parameter-n.html

The solution was to split the --extdir and directory path into separate parameters like so:

```
# Application parameters.  Add parameters as needed starting from 1
wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.apache.activemq.console.Main
wrapper.app.parameter.2=--extdir 
wrapper.app.parameter.3=/opt/apache-activemq-5.8.0/lib/companyname
wrapper.app.parameter.4=start
```